# Solution of system of differential equations using Laplace Transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

[image: Circuit Image]

The question is

> For the circuit shown in Figure, find the currents using Laplace transformation and without using Laplace transformation assuming zero currents and charge when $t=0.$

The equations written using Kirchhoff's Voltage Law (mesh analysis) are
\begin{align*}
 I'_1 =&-I_1R_1/L+I_2 R_1/L + E/L &\\
 I'_2 =&-I_2/(C(R_1+R_2))+(-I_1R_1/L+I_2 R_1/L + E/L)R_1/(R_1+R_2)
\end{align*}

The first part was done using

$\begin{alignat}{1}
\left[ \begin{array}{r}
I'_1\\I'_2
\end{array} \right] = &\left[ \begin{array}{rr}
-R_1/L  &  R_1/L \\
-R^2_1/(L(R_1+R_2)) &-1/(C(R_1+R_2))+( R^2_1/(L(R_1+R_2) )
\end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{r}
I_1\\I_2
\end{array} \right] \\+ &\left[ \begin{array}{r}
E/L\\ER_1/(L(R_1+R_2))
\end{array} \right]
\end{alignat}
$

and the answer is

$\mathbf{y}=139.44\mathsf{e}^{-1.54 t}\left[ \begin{array}{rr}
2  \\
0.46 
\end{array} \right] -47.58 \mathsf{e}^{-0.26 t}\left[ \begin{array}{rr}
2   \\
1.74
\end{array} \right]  +\left[ \begin{array}{rr}
100 \\
0
\end{array} \right]$

---

Now, for the second part using Laplace transformation, I'm not getting the correct answer.

$\left[ \begin{array}{rr}
s+R_1/L  &  -R_1/L \\
R^2_1/(L(R_1+R_2)) &s+1/(C(R_1+R_2))-( R^2_1/(L(R_1+R_2) )
\end{array} \right]\left[ \begin{array}{r}
I_1(s)\\I_2(s)
\end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{r}
E/sL\\ER_1/(sL(R_1+R_2))
\end{array} \right]$

For instance, for $i_2(t),$ I'm getting

$\displaystyle \frac{400\,\sqrt{41}\,{\mathrm{e}}^{-\frac{9\,t}{10}} \,\sinh \left(\frac{\sqrt{41}\,t}{10}\right)}{41}$

Why am I not getting the same answer when using Laplace Transform?

Note that:  $R_1=2\,\Omega$, $R_2=8\,\Omega$, $L=1\,\text{H}$, $C=0.5\,\text{F}$, $E=200\,\text{V}$

Update: Thats how I solved the problem as a system of differential equations

$
    y_1=\mathsf{e}^{ \big(-\frac{9}{10}\big)t} \Bigg( -\frac{200\,\sqrt{41}}{41} \mathsf{e}^{ \big(-\frac{\sqrt{41}}{10}\big)t}\big(
    \frac{\sqrt{41}}{4}+\frac{11}{4}\big)+ \frac{200\,\sqrt{41}}{41}\mathsf{e}^{\big(\frac{\sqrt{41}}{10}\big)t}\big(
    -\frac{\sqrt{41}}{4}+\frac{11}{4} \big)\Bigg)  +
    100 \\
    =-\frac{200\,\sqrt{41}}{41}\mathsf{e}^{ \big(-\frac{9}{10}\big)t} \Bigg(  \mathsf{e}^{ \big(-\frac{\sqrt{41}}{10}\big)t}\big(
    \frac{\sqrt{41}}{4}+\frac{11}{4}\big)+\mathsf{e}^{\big(\frac{\sqrt{41}}{10}\big)t}\big(
    \frac{\sqrt{41}}{4}-\frac{11}{4} \big) \Bigg) +
    100 \\
    =-\frac{200\,\sqrt{41}}{41}\mathsf{e}^{ \big(-\frac{9}{10}\big)t} \Bigg(  \frac{\sqrt{41}}{4}\Bigg(\mathsf{e}^{ \big(-\frac{\sqrt{41}}{10}\big)t}+\mathsf{e}^{ \big(-\frac{\sqrt{41}}{10}\big)t}\Bigg)
    -\frac{11}{4} \Bigg(\mathsf{e}^{\big(\frac{-\sqrt{41}}{10}\big)t} -\mathsf{e}^{\big(\frac{\sqrt{41}}{10}\big)t}   \Bigg) +
    100 \\
    =-\frac{200\,\sqrt{41}}{41}\mathsf{e}^{ \big(-\frac{9}{10}\big)t} \Bigg(  -\frac{\sqrt{41}}{2}\cosh\frac{\sqrt{41}}{10}t
    +\frac{11}{2} \sinh\frac{\sqrt{41}}{10}t \Bigg)  +
    100 \\
$

I'm not getting the correct polarity, what am I doing wrong here

Answer (score 1):

### Using the Differential Equation

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
I'_1 \\ I'_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 2 \\ -2/5 & 1/5
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
I_1 \\ I_2
\end{bmatrix}
+\begin{bmatrix}
200 \\ 40
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Your time domain mesh analysis equations are correct, but the **system solution is not**. Using *Wolfram Mathematica*$^{(*)}$, I got:

$$
\begin{alignat}{1}
i_1(t) &= \frac{100}{41} e^{^{-\frac{9t}{10}}}\! \cdot \! \left[11 \sqrt{41} \sinh \left(\frac{\sqrt{41} t}{10}\right)-41 \cosh \left(\frac{\sqrt{41} t}{10}\right)\right]+100
\\[5px]
i_2(t) &= \frac{400 \sqrt{41} ~ e^{-\frac{9 t}{10}} \sinh \left(\frac{\sqrt{41} t}{10}\right)}{41}
\end{alignat}
$$

In terms of numerical values:

$$
  \begin{alignat}{1}
   i_1(t) &\approx -135.90 e^{-1.54t} + 35.90 e^{-0.26t} 
   \\[5px]
   i_2(t) &\approx -31.23 e^{-1.54t} + 31.23 e^{-0.26t}
  \end{alignat}
$$

Let us solve it manually, step by step, so that you can identify your specific mistake(s).

**1. The system and its solution**

• General Solution = Homogeneous Solution + Particular Solution:
$$
\vec{i}~\!'=A\cdot \vec i + \vec b \implies \vec i = \vec i_h + \vec i_p
$$

• True (Actual) Solution = General Solution with the Initial Conditions applied:
$$
\vec{i} ~~~ \text{and} ~~~ \vec i_0 = \vec{i}(0) = \vec0 
$$
**2. The homogeneous solution**

• Eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ of $A$:
$$
\begin{align}
\det \left( {A - \lambda I} \right) &=
\begin{vmatrix}
-2 - \lambda & 2 \\ -2/5 & 1/5 - \lambda
\end{vmatrix}
\\&= \frac 1 5 \cdot (5\lambda^2 + 9\lambda + 2)
\quad \implies \lambda_1 = \frac{-9-\sqrt{41}}{10},~~\lambda_2 = \frac{-9+\sqrt{41}}{10}
\end{align}
$$

• Eigenvectors $\vec v_1$ and $\vec v_2$ of $A$:
$$
\lambda_1 = \frac{-9-\sqrt{41}}{10}:
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 - \lambda_1 & \!\!\!2 \\ -2/5 & \!\!\!1/5 -\lambda_1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
p \\ q
\end{bmatrix} 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
\implies
\vec v_1 =
\begin{bmatrix}
\left(11+\sqrt{41}\right)/4 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
\\[25px]
\lambda_2 = \frac{-9+\sqrt{41}}{10}:
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 - \lambda_2 & \!\!\!2 \\ -2/5 & \!\!\!1/5 -\lambda_2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
r \\ s
\end{bmatrix} 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
\implies
\vec v_2 =
\begin{bmatrix}
\left(11-\sqrt{41}\right)/4 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
• Homogeneous solution:
$$
\vec i_h = c_1e^{\lambda_1 t} \vec v_1 + c_2e^{\lambda_2 t} \vec v_2 = c_1e^{^{\frac{-9-\sqrt{41}}{10}t}}
\begin{bmatrix}
\left(11+\sqrt{41}\right)/4 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix} + c_2e^{^{\frac{-9+\sqrt{41}}{10}t}} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\left(11-\sqrt{41}\right)/4 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

**3. The particular solution**

• Guess (linear polynomial in this case):
$$
\vec i_p = \vec c ~t + \vec d =
\begin{bmatrix}
c_1 \\ c_2
\end{bmatrix}t
+\begin{bmatrix}
d_1 \\ d_2
\end{bmatrix} \implies \vec{i}_p~\!\!\!' = \vec c
$$
• Plugging into the system:
$$
\vec c = A\cdot \big(\vec c ~t + \vec d \big) + \vec b \implies \vec0 = \left(A \vec c\right)t + \big(A\vec d + \vec b - \vec c \big) \implies 
\begin{cases}
\!\!A \vec c = \vec0 \\[1ex]
\!\!A\vec d + \vec b - \vec c = \vec0
\end{cases}
\\[35px]
\begin{alignat}{1}
A \vec c = \vec0 &\implies
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 2 \\ -2/5 & 1/5
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
c_1 \\ c_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
\implies
\vec c = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
\\[5px]
A \vec d = \vec c - \vec b &\implies
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 2 \\ -2/5 & 1/5
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
d_1 \\ d_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0-200 \\ 0-40
\end{bmatrix}
\implies
\vec d = \begin{bmatrix}
100 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{alignat}
\\[2px]
$$

• Particular solution:
$$
\vec i_p = \vec c ~t + \vec d = \vec d = 
\begin{bmatrix}
100 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
\\
$$

**4. The general solution**
$$
\vec i = \vec i_h + \vec i_p = 
c_1e^{^{\frac{-9-\sqrt{41}}{10}t}}
\begin{bmatrix}
\left(11+\sqrt{41}\right)/4 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix} + c_2e^{^{\frac{-9+\sqrt{41}}{10}t}} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\left(11-\sqrt{41}\right)/4 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix}
100 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

**5. The true solution**

• Applying the initial conditions:
$$
\begin{alignat}{1}
\vec i_0 = \vec0 &\implies c_1
\begin{bmatrix}
\left(11+\sqrt{41}\right)/4 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix} + c_2 
\begin{bmatrix}
\left(11-\sqrt{41}\right)/4 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix}
100 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
\\[5px]
&\implies c_1 = -\frac{200}{\sqrt{41}}, ~~ c_2 = \frac{200}{\sqrt{41}}
\end{alignat}
$$

• True solution:
$$
\begin{alignat}{1}
\vec i &= -\frac{200}{\sqrt{41}} \cdot e^{^{\frac{-9-\sqrt{41}}{10}t}}
\begin{bmatrix}
\left(11+\sqrt{41}\right)/4 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix} + \frac{200}{\sqrt{41}} \cdot e^{^{\frac{-9+\sqrt{41}}{10}t}} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\left(11-\sqrt{41}\right)/4 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix}
100 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{alignat}
$$

• True solution (numerical values):

(Note that we obtained the same solution given by *Mathematica* for $i_1$ and $i_2$)
$$
\bbox[6px,border:1.5px solid black] {
\vec i(t) \approx
-31.23 \cdot e^{-1.54t}
\begin{bmatrix}
4.35 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix} + 31.23 \cdot e^{-0.26t} 
\begin{bmatrix}
1.15 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix}
100 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
}
\\
$$

---

### Using Laplace Transform

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
s+2 & -2 \\ 2/5 & s-1/5
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
I_1(s) \\ I_2(s)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
200/s \\ 40/s
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Your Laplace domain matrix system is correct too. Let us solve it:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
I_1(s) \\ I_2(s)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
s+2 & -2 \\ 2/5 & s-1/5
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
200/s \\ 40/s
\end{bmatrix}
\implies
\begin{cases}
I_1(s) = \dfrac{1000s+200}{5s^3+9s^2+2s} \\[1ex]
I_2(s) = \dfrac{200}{5s^2+9s+2}
\end{cases}
$$

Now, anti-transforming, we get the same results:

$$
\begin{alignat}{1}
i_1(t) &= \mathscr{L}^{-1}\left[ I_1(s) \right] ~&= \frac{100}{41} e^{^{-\frac{9t}{10}}}\! \cdot \! \left[11 \sqrt{41} \sinh \left(\frac{\sqrt{41} t}{10}\right)-41 \cosh \left(\frac{\sqrt{41} t}{10}\right)\right]+100
\\[5px]
i_2(t) &= \mathscr{L}^{-1}\left[ I_2(s) \right] ~&= \frac{400 \sqrt{41} ~ e^{-\frac{9 t}{10}} \sinh \left(\frac{\sqrt{41} t}{10}\right)}{41}
\end{alignat}
$$

---

${(*)}$ Here is a [screenshot of the commands used in *Mathematica 12.0*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4yPX.png) and their results. Note that *solution1* and *solution2* are the same, the difference is that one is written with the exponential function and the other with hyperbolic functions, namely:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
   \sinh(x) = \dfrac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2} \quad 
 & \quad \cosh(x)=\dfrac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Diana, about your update, you just made some sign mistakes on the 3rd line. Look:
$$
 =-\frac{200\,\sqrt{41}}{41}\mathsf{e}^{ \big(-\frac{9}{10}\big)t} \Bigg(  \frac{\sqrt{41}}{4}\Bigg(\mathsf{e}^{ \big(-\frac{\sqrt{41}}{10}\big)t}+\mathsf{e}^{ \big( \bbox[yellow,0px,border:1.5px solid red]{-}\,\frac{\sqrt{41}}{10}\big)t}\Bigg)
     -\,\frac{11}{4} \Bigg(\mathsf{e}^{\big(\bbox[yellow,border:1.0px solid red]{-}\frac{\sqrt{41}}{10}\big)t} -\mathsf{e}^{\big(\bbox[yellow,1.5px,border:1.5px solid red]{^~}\frac{\sqrt{41}}{10}\big)t}   \Bigg) +
    100 \\
$$

Comment: The correct version should be:

$$
 =-\frac{200\,\sqrt{41}}{41}\mathsf{e}^{ \big(-\frac{9}{10}\big)t} \Bigg(  \frac{\sqrt{41}}{4}\Bigg(\mathsf{e}^{ \big(-\frac{\sqrt{41}}{10}\big)t}+\mathsf{e}^{ \big( \frac{\sqrt{41}}{10}\big)t}\Bigg)
     -\,\frac{11}{4} \Bigg(\mathsf{e}^{\big(\frac{\sqrt{41}}{10}\big)t} -\mathsf{e}^{\big(-\frac{\sqrt{41}}{10}\big)t}   \Bigg) +
    100 \\
$$

Comment: Which leads to:

$$
\begin{alignat}{1}
&=-&\frac{200\,\sqrt{41}}{41}\mathsf{e}^{ \big(-\frac{9}{10}\big)t} \Bigg( \frac{\sqrt{41}}{2}\cosh\frac{\sqrt{41}}{10}t
    -\frac{11}{2} \sinh\frac{\sqrt{41}}{10}t \Bigg)  +
    100 \\
&=&\frac{200\,\sqrt{41}}{41}\mathsf{e}^{ \big(-\frac{9}{10}\big)t} \Bigg(\frac{11}{2} \sinh\frac{\sqrt{41}}{10}t - \frac{\sqrt{41}}{2}\cosh\frac{\sqrt{41}}{10}t
    \Bigg)  +
    100 \\
&=&\frac{100}{41}\mathsf{e}^{ \big(-\frac{9}{10}\big)t} \Bigg(11\sqrt{41} \sinh\frac{\sqrt{41}}{10}t - 41\cosh\frac{\sqrt{41}}{10}t
    \Bigg)  +
    100 \\
\end{alignat}
$$